# facebook invite friends with notification

Tags: php, facebook

I want to invite multiple friends using multi friends selector dialog of facebook.

I am developing a site and in which I want this functionality.

I have done with the application invitation and invited user can see the invitation but the link in invitation is not working and that user have no Notification on top.

Is there any perfect example of invite friends to facebook application?

I have tried this one http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/

Comment: Have you read the notification on top of the page you linked to?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

The method you have been trying to implement is deprecated and will stop working soon anyway.

Comment: I have tried this one too. using above method user is able to see notification for a while on page reload, then after it is no more there.

Comment: I think that once you've sent the notification, and they've received it, there's nothing more you can do, in my experience Facebook is not always consistent with how they handle these things.

Answer (score 1):

**invite facebook friend from your website,use this small lines of code and send invitation to all facebook friends to visit your website.i also used this script its working nicely. 
your domain must be *ssl certified* because facebook not allowing unsecured domains.**

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
FB.init({
appId:'APP_ID',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog'
});
}
</script>


//HTML Code
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

add this below code to your website main page..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (top.location!= self.location)
{
top.location = self.location
}
</script>
```

for more detail you can check:- http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html